# How to await a subscribe call to return in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have tried most of the options on stack overflow so far and had little success. The current code leaves page empty.[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wICxD.png)

Comment: Please give a [mre], but note that observables and promises are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return the `Observable` and use `switchMap` and `forkJoinrx` to switch to the new observable.

Try this:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
getAllPagesFromTag(workspaceId: string, localTagId: string): Observable<any> {
   let data: any = [];
   let ids: any = [];
   return this.afs
     ... 
     ...
     .pipe(
      switchMap((actions) => {
           return forkJoin(...actions.map((a) => {
              data.push(a.payload.doc.data());
              ids.push(a.payload.doc.id);
              return this.pageService.getWorkSpacePage(`${workspaceId}`, id);
           }));
      }),
      map(d => return data.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, id: ids[index], page: d }))),
    )
}));
}
```

Something like that should work. Then you can do:

```
getAllPagesFromTag('1', '2').subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

To return a promise, just tack on a `.toPromise()` at the end.

```
getAllPagesFromTag(workspaceId: string, localTagId: string): Promise<any> {
  return this.afs.
   ....
 .....
    ).toPromise();
}
```